# Youtube video load in a-frame

Tags: html, aframe

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>multiple pseudo scenes</title>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.5.0/aframe.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
<a-assets>
<video id="video-src" autoplay="false" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?
 v=Uz12cLvkVYY"></video>
</a-assets>
<a-video id="video-screen" src="#video-src"  position="1.591 2.206 -11" 
width="30" height="13">
</a-video>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I want to load youtube video in a scene using a-frame. But it does not show anything. How to load a youtube video using a-frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd be very convenient if you could just drop a youtube URL into a `<video>` tag, but that's unfortunately not how it works.  To embed a youtube video in your page you need to follow one of the methods in the youtube [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player), which ends up one way or another inserting an iframe in your page containing the video.

And [iframes can't be used inside a-frame](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/faq.html#how-do-i-display-lt-iframe-gt-s-or-render-html-in-a-frame):

> There is no way for the browser to display `<iframe>`s within WebGL. While it is possible to overlay an `<iframe>` on top of the canvas, the `<iframe>` will not display in VR nor can it integrate with the scene.

Further on in the a-frame docs, youtube is [specifically mentioned](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/faq.html#can-i-render-youtube-videos-as-a-texture):

> **Can I render YouTube videos as a texture?**  No. You could proxy YouTube videos as a texture or download them locally to serve, but that is against their terms of service.

...which suggests that video is possible, but youtube is not (for legal, rather than technical, reasons).  If you need to do this you'll need a non-youtube video source.

Comment: So can't I load youtube video in a-frame?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no, you can't. Sorry!